# Flash Application automation using Python and which tool

Tags: selenium, flash, pycharm, sikuli, browser-automation

I have an application built on flash and that runs only on Internet Explorer. Sample screen of the application looks as shared. Also, I have shared object details.

I want to know, Can I choose Python language + Any tool to automate. I have browsed  for tools like Selenium, PyCharm, Sikuli etc. But not able to figure out the exact tools along with Python and other settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/automated-ui-testing-of-flash-flex-applications/). We used it to automate Flex application with C# as auto script.

But it's not free software.